# Why are Frozen's Elsa and Anna excluded from the Disney Princesses franchise?

Tags: character, disney, frozen

*[Disney Princess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disney_Princess)* is a famous Disney franchise and most of Disney's famous princesses are part of it, including Merida from *Brave* and Rapunzel from *Tangled*. But why are Elsa and Anna from *Frozen* kept separate and not included in the franchise?

Why are *Frozen*'s Elsa and Anna excluded from the Disney Princesses line?

Comment: According to french wikipedia they are actually part of disney princess https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elsa_(Disney) last line of the first paragraph `Elsa et sa sœur Anna font partie de la franchise des Princesses Disney.`

Comment: The real question: Why isn't _Princess_ Leia a Disney Princess?

Comment: Elsa and Anna aren't the only ones excluded.  There are many princesses not included.  This is a marketing thing.

Comment: @KimberlyW Star Wars not animated and not made for kids, Disney accrue it after she became too old to be called princes.

Comment: @AnkitSharma `too old to be called princess` is there a princess age limit? I assumed they only stopped being a princess when `A: They became queen` or `B: Well lets just say something really bad happened to them`.

Comment: @Y12K then you can make anyone princess, maybe Lady Sif too

Comment: @Ankit: may I invite you to take a look at the Wikipedia entry for [Princess Anne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anne,_Princess_Royal)?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Being a [Disney Princess](http://princess.disney.com) is not just a matter of being a princess from a Disney property, it's a question of marketing. The collection of Disney Princesses is used together in other materials, things like direct-to-video releases, books, games, etc. There's an article on a [Disney Wikia](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Disney_Princess) that has some more details, but that's the gist of it.

Frozen was such a success, that Anna and Elsa got their own marketing segment:
 [Disney Frozen](http://frozen.disney.com). At some point, the popularity of the sisters may go down and one or both may get rolled into the "Princess" marketing machine.

Comment: Can't imagine they'd get moved separately - their stories and characters are far too closely tied.

Comment: @brichins You do realize that you're responding to a claim about a "marketing machine" with a point about "stories and characters", right?

Comment: The things to be marketed are in fact characters of a story. The story of the characters will affect the marketing because it is the story that creates the demand in the marketplace. This is not to explicitly support the comment, necessarily, but you shouldn't dismiss it like that.

Comment: @Segfault If indeed the primary or only marketable aspect of the characters is the relationship between them (as is probably the case for, say, Timon and Pumba), then sure, the marketing machine will probably recognize that. But I'm not sure that's true in this case.

Comment: To quote from RBTI: They're "from the other studio"............. :)

Answer (score 39):

There is no official word from Disney, but I can say these two things for facts:

- Elsa is a Queen.  So, making her a Princess would be almost impossible.
- Elsa and Anna represent 25% of all Disney merchandising sales.  **Twenty five percent**.  Keeping them separate from all other Disney Princesses is probably the best move financially.

Comment: Well, Elsa **was** a princess for several years, until her parents died...

Comment: True, which is why making her a Princess again would be a step backwards.

Comment: Nah, that's really far fetched IMO, and not a reason why she's not included.

Comment: Anyway, your other point appears to be [correct](http://disneyprincess.wikia.com/wiki/Elsa): *She was supposed join the Disney Princess line up with Anna, but due to the "Frozen" franchise being so successful Disney decided that it wasn't necessary to add Anna and Elsa to Disney Princess*.

Comment: Related viewing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cVt5w6ce3hM

Comment: Elsa being a queen is the kind of technicality that Disney has readily ignored in the past. Pocahontas didn't have the concept of monarchy, and Mulan wasn't even her own country's equivalent of a monarch's daughter.

Comment: Source for your revenue statistic? Wikipedia says (in the [last paragraph of the relevant section]((https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frozen_(franchise)#Merchandise))) they had a 22% growth in revenue (over previous year) for the quarter that the movie came out, and that *Frozen* was the largest contributor, but I'd be interested to see an authoritative source with more details.

Comment: @GGMG : Technically, when Pocahontas visited Britain, she was officially considered a princess, despite her not inheriting her father's position in her tribe.

Comment: It mighy also have something to do with the animation style not fitting in with the other movies when drawing the princesses together on merchandise.

Comment: @ThomasMoors, that hasn't stopped Tangled. They did a 2D illustration of Rapunzel to include her with the rest.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is in line with the previous. I just wanted to mention that
SuperCarlinBrothers have researched and made [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cVt5w6ce3hM) about this particular issue but in short, Frozen is just a powerhouse of a franchise on its own without the need for them to be Princesses.

There is a great chart at the 3:45 mark which shows that Frozen would account for 25% of the total ticket sales if added to the combined total of the other films. Most other princesses come in at around 8% - 15% each.

At the time they made that video, Frozen's merchandising sales were the 3rd largest behind Star Wars and Cars. They simply outclass the other princesses in terms of their value.

Comment: I wonder whether *Frozen* merchandise is really more popular than that of past films, or if the current rates are mostly due to timing. Disney marketing only [started pushing Princess-specific merchandise about 15 years ago](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Disney_Princess#History), and *Frozen* and *Tangled* are the only well-received [Modern Era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disney_Princess#Modern_era) princess movies made since then.

Comment: I would expect the Classic/Renaissance princesses have cumulatively sold as much (or more) than *Frozen*, but that most kids received Classic princess items years ago, either new or inherited from older relatives. *Frozen* is brand-new so there's no second-hand market yet, so buying new directly from Disney-licensed sources is basically the only option.

Answer (score -3):

I think Anna would be more qualified to be an official Disney Princess than Elsa. One of the requirements I heard about was that they had to have an animal companion. While INITIALLY Sven was only Kristoff's companion, it can be argued that Sven became Anna's companion as well once Anna chose to be with Kristoff over Hans qualifying her as one. But still, she's not until Disney says she is since they're using the term as a title rather than a definition.

Comment: Welcome to Movies.SE! This doesn't really answer the question until the last sentence; you should edit it to focus on why they *aren't* Disney princesses, rather than why Anna should be.